# How do I select an appropriate value for 'eps' when using SLSQP with Scipy minimize?

Tags: python, scipy

I've written the following optimisation code:

```
guess = [1/6] * 6
bounds = [(0.0,1.0)] * 6                          
cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  1 - sum(x)}
result = minimize(function, guess, (instrument, sample),\
  bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP', tol=0.01, constraints=cons,\
  options={'disp': False ,'eps' : 1e-2})
```

The result should be a vector of length 6, with each value being `0<x<1` and `sum(x) = 1`.

I have set a tolerance of 0.01, which I believe means that the optimizer will terminate when it's within 1% of a minima.

What I'm confused about is the `'eps'` term. I'm not entirely sure what it means, or how it relates to the tolerance setting. How do I pick a reasonable value, and what are the consequences of being too high or low?

Answer (score -1):

Well, according to the [docs](https://www.docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html), `eps` is the

> Step size used for numerical approximation of the jacobian.

Re what's a good value you may find some quite specific guidance in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) section "Practical considerations using floating point arithmetic"